# В теле ответа приходит object scala.Unit

Tags: java, scala

В общем, был код, который использовал Java 8 и Scalatra 2.5.0 и я поднял Java до 11, а Scalatra до 2.7.1.

После контроллер начал вместо пустого ответа, возвращать `object scala.Unit`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам метод не менялся и представляет из себя:

```
post("/settings") {
      blahblahblah...
      Unit
    }
```

Как можно пофиксить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать обернуть в `None` что бы ответа не было